# superfish menu hiding behind table

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, superfish

If you look at the homepage of the following site (in IE7 only):

http://cmse.bemoore.com/

the superfish dropdown disappears behind the table. I have tried playing with the z-index to no avail.

Can anyone make any suggestions what to try?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself.  By adding the following 2 lines to the .main-navig class:

```
/* Added to fix z-index bug */
z-index: 1000;
position: relative;
```

basically the `<div>` containing the dropdown menu needs to have a higher z-index than the divs below it.  Whew ! Thought that was going to be harder.

Also the `position: relative` is key.